# Visual Studio Installer UI integration

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer

Is it possible to have a custom UI for Visual Studio 2013 Installer project ( https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d )? 
What's different between setup.exe and .msi? 
Is there a good example explaining VS Installer?

The task is to create VS2013 like installer, which downloads the latest files from the web (URL is hardcoded). As I understand, setup.exe should get the latest .msi file from the web, download it and run it? Therefore, setup.exe needs to be customized somehow. Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry for bunch of questions, i'm new to C#/VS, having lack of its basis.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 no longer has installer projects. Exactly what kind of installer are you asking about.

Comment: @JohnSaunders [Visual Studio Extension for installer project is available](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)

Comment: @RahulNikate: thanks. I didn't know about those. Still no MSBUILD integration, so still a non-starter for me.

Comment: Welcome @JohnSaunders. This extension provides the same functionality that were exists in Visual Studio 2010 for Visual Studio Installer projects.

Comment: Visual Studio installer project template is no longer shipped with Visual Studio. You could either use XCopy/MS Deploy for web deployment.
To create installer packages, you can use InstallShield

Comment: @MaheshKava I don't need web deployment, it's desktop based project, .msi/whatever files should be hosted on apache/nginx server.

Comment: ..and again @maheshKava, you CAN down load an installer project template for VS 2013. Read the previous comments!

Answer (score 1):

If this extension actually has the same functionality as VS2010 installer projects, then, this sort of UI extensibility does not exist.

There is a very limited capability to have simple customization, but it's really *very* limited.

If you need a nice UI, then you should have a program that runs after installation to interact with the person doing the installation.

Comment: I wonder how Microsoft did their VS installer. I saw [XeamVisualInstaller](http://www.xeam-solutions.com/products/visual-installer.html) it uses WiX, but free version has limited functional.

Comment: WiX is open source software.. the full functionality is there.  Microsoft created their own custom bootstrapper application to drive the UI for VS setup.  That has nothing to do with WiX.

Answer (score 1):

In the VS setup world, setup.exe is a bootstrapper that installs prerequisites and then runs your MSI. If you have no prerequisites you don't need setup.exe.

There are other tools that let you customize the UI - it's just that VS doesn't support that. Tools like WiX and (full) InstallShield let you build your own UI within the capabilities of MSI dialogs. In the case where there is just one MSI file being installed that's usually all that people do.

Note that MSI dialogs are nothing to do with .NET dialogs or controls - that's why they are very basic. There's no C# in there, just the controls and dialogs that MSI supports internally. You don't get to use your own C# dialogs at all.

In the case where there are multiple MSI files that you want to install as if it's a single product (SQL Server, Office, Visual Studio too I believe) then you need a wrapper (WiX has Burn bootstrapper, InstallShield has a chainer) to make it look like a single setup. If this is the case OR you want you own completely custom C# dialog UI then you write your own - or build on the WiX framework like these guys:

http://www.wrightfully.com/part-1-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-overview/

http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/

The architecture is based on this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb309215(v=vs.85).aspx

and MsiSetExternalUIRecord.  Basically you write code to install one or MSIs while Windows Installer calls back into your code for each event during the install. This is where you have you own startup dialogs, and Windows Installer will call back with progress messages for you to display, as well as errors, files in use situations etc. It's easier to use a tool like WiX that's provided most of the framework for that.

So it depends what you mean by custom dialogs. If you just mean "not like Visual Studio" or "I need a dialog to enter something that VS doesn't offer" and you have one MSI to install, then WiX, InstallShield, Advanced Installer and other tools will do that. If you mean "I want my own completely custom C# dialogs" then you need to write your own using C# interop with MsiSetExternalUIRecord or use WiX boostrapper, which I believe is the only one out there - correct me if that's wrong.