# Create Setup for window form application with menu on left

Tags: winforms, setup-project

Thanks in advance

I have need to create the setup of window form application in .Net Framework.
I have requirement to add menu on the left appear/highlighted while the progress of installer goes on similar to that we have in case of SQL Server installation progress.I [SQL Server Menu on left example](http://vibellet.free.fr/blogsmsdn/SQLServer2008R2NovemberCTPInstallationSt_BABF/image_11.png)

Can I do that with Installshield or in Visual Studio 2010. Please provide me other example

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with a Visual Studio setup project. That means it's a question of which tool is a good one for your requirement. I know WiX can do this with a custom Burn bundle, and perhaps InstallShield too.

It's not clear why you want that appearance because the SQL setup consists of many separate features, MSI files, and configuration steps. So it bundles together many MSI files and executables with multiple features. A Visual Studio setup has only a single Windows Installer feature.

The general method used to wrap an MSI in a custom UI is described here as a short C++ example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb309215(v=vs.85).aspx

and it's essentially the same question here:

[Visual Studio Installer UI integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047849/visual-studio-installer-ui-integration)